# How to get element based on page url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have navigation in form of **ul** and **li**. If url is `http://mydomain.com/somewiredpath/page21.htm?p=1` how can i get **li** element with this url? I don't care about rest of the url, need just li with "page21.htm".

```
<ul id="navig">
        <li>
            <a href=".../page1.htm"><imgsrc="..."></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=".../page2.htm"><imgsrc="..."></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=".../page3.htm"><imgsrc="..."></a></li>
                <li><a href=".../page4.htm"><imgsrc="..."></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

PS: i'm going to add some styles to matched and parent elements, so if there is already some jquery function/plugin for that, it would be great to know.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? setting the **LI** element active for the current url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findLi(pagename) {
    return $('#navig a[href*="' + pagename + '"]').closest("li");
}
```

Comment: `>= 0`, not `> 0`, to allow for the `href` having the value "page23.html". (`attr` may return the attribute, which will still be relative, as opposed to the property that will be resolved. I don't know what it did in jQuery 1.5.x; in 1.6 in theory it will get the attribute, specifically.)

Comment: Also recommend that if you write `$(this)` more than once in a handler or iterator, cache it. Every time you do that, there are multiple function calls and a memory allocation. Actually, in this case, you don't need the first one at all, just use `this.href` directly.

Comment: fixed >= and fixed return.. you cant return a value from inside each()

Comment: @ariel: Yeah, as the OP is using jQuery, there you go. :-)

Comment: $("#navig a").each(function() {if(path.indexOf(this.href)>=0){ $(this).closest("li").addClass('current');}});